# Objective c can i use a popover to display a text and send a diferente value?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, popover

i am trying to use a different value than the text showed by the popover

```
data = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

        @"SPECIALTY_1", @"fieldName1",
        NSLocalizedString(@"Specialty 1:", nil), @"desc1",
        specialty1, @"value1",
        edit, @"edit1",
        @"SPECIALTY_2", @"fieldName2",
        NSLocalizedString(@"Specialty 2:", nil), @"desc2",
        specialty2, @"value2", 
        edit, @"edit2", nil];

NSArray *specialties = listData.specialties;
NSArray *Id = listData.specialtyID;
if (specialties) {
    [data setObject:specialties forKey:@"list1"];
    [data setObject:specialties forKey:@"list2"];
    //[data setObject:specialties forKey:@"list2"];
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.  What popover?  What value?

Comment: i go the lists being loaded with the specialties array and it shows the text i want them to show the text and send a value with an id of the selected text in the lsit